# Не могу найти решить проблему в TextMesh

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if ((curPage * 10 + i) < objSpawner.maxObjects) 
    {
        if (objectDelivery [i] == false)
            go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text += 
                collorObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] +
                kindOfObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] +
                propObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] +
                stickerObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] +
                massObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] +
                destinationText [curPage * 10 + i] + "\n";
        else if (objectDelivery [i] == true)
            go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text += 
                "<color=#00000055>" + collorObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +
                "<color=#00000055>" + kindOfObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +
                "<color=#00000055>" + propObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +
                "<color=#00000055>" + stickerObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +
                "<color=#00000055>" + massObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +
                "<color=#00000055>" + destinationText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" + "\n";
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать журнал с записями, по 10 строк на одной странице. Если `objectDelivery [i] == false`, то цвет строки обычный, если `true`, то становится прозрачным.

`curPage` номер страницы, по умолчанию 0, когда тыкаю стрелку вправо (она есть и работает), то `curPage` становится 1, ну и так далее. Все это хорошо работает и показывает все, что нужно (в начале первые 10 строк, на следующей странице вторые 10 строк и так далее), но!
Проблема следующая: если `objectDelivery [2] == true` (2 для примера, вообще любой индекс МЕНЬШЕ 10), то прозрачность меняется у объектов с индексами 2, 12, 22 и так далее. Если `objectDelivery [11] == true` (больше или равен 10), то прозрачность не меняется совсем. Намудрил я, конечно, знатно, но если не использовать `curPage`, то он весь список выводит на экран, что очень плохо.
Собственно, проблема `>=10` от того, что `i` указана до `10`, `<10` наверно имеет те же корни, но как реализовать прозрачность строки для конкретного объекта, придумать не могу

---

Обновление:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    // для того, чтобы на странице отображались ТОЛЬКО 10 строк (без этого отображаются все строки
    if ((curPage * 10 + i) < objSpawner.maxObjects) 
    { // проверяет, чтобы индекс не вышел за пределы maxObjects (и задает кол-во страниц
        if (objectDelivery [i] == false)
            go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text += 
                collorObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "\n";
        else if (objectDelivery [i] == true)
            go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text += 
                "<color=#00000055>" + collorObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +"\n";
    }
}
```

Вот немного сократил. Прозрачной я хочу сделать только одну строку, которая соответствует определенному индексу (от 0 до maxObjects), при этом первые 10 строк расположены на первой странице, вторые на второй и так далее. Вот эта часть говорит, на какой странице будет строка, соответствующая определеному индексу `[curPage * 10 + i]`

Comment: Странный код.  Сложно дать ответ, потому что много переменных, которые ни о чем не говорят. А прозрачность меняется потому что  цикл- это очевидно. Избавься от него и все будет ок. Зачем проходить все страницы- сделай прозрачной только текущую, а потом из массива достань только нужную и сделай цветной ....

Comment: @ValeraKvip обновил вопрос. Без цикла все строки отображаются на одной странице, увы. И мне не страницы нужно делать прозрачными, а только конкретные строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так (я в двух местах заменил `i` на `curPage * 10 + i`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // для того, чтобы на странице отображались ТОЛЬКО 10 строк (без этого отображаются все строки
                if ((curPage * 10 + i) < objSpawner.maxObjects) { // проверяет, чтобы индекс не вышел за пределы maxObjects (и задает кол-во страниц
                    if (objectDelivery [curPage * 10 + i] == false)
                        go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text += 
                        collorObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "\n";
                    else if (objectDelivery [curPage * 10 + i] == true)
                        go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text += 
                        "<color=#00000055>" + collorObjectText [curPage * 10 + i] + "</color>" +"\n";
    }
    }
```